# backend api is not adding the data to the database

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, backend, mern

So, I am creating a ecommerce website and when a seller upload there product details it stores it in a common mongodb database and then stores the product-id assigned by mongo to the product in the seller database.

The problem I am facing is that the product is getting added to the product database but the productId is not getting added to the seller database

Seller Database Model:-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const schema = mongoose.Schema

const sellerDbModel = new schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    product: { type: Array, required: false }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Seller-Data", sellerDbModel)
```

API:-

```
const addProductIdToSellerData = asyncHandler( async(req, res) => {
    const { id, productId } = req.body

    try{
        const result = await sellerAuthModel.updateOne(
            { _id: id }, // Filter criteria
            { $push: { product: productId } } // Update operation
          );
      
          // Check if the update was successful
          if (result.nModified === 1) {
            console.log('Element added to the array.');
            res.send('added')
            return true;
          } else {
            console.log('Element was not added to the array.');
            res.send('not added')
            return false;
          }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

sellerAuthRouter.post('/addProductId', sellerAuthController.addProductIdToSellerData)
```

calling the API in react component:-

```
const addProductId = async(id, productId) => {
    try{
        const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/sellerAuth/addProductId`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: id,
                productId: productId
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        return data
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

the react component:-

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { addProductAPI } from '../../utils/backendAPI';
import { addProductId } from '../../utils/sellerAPI';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const AddProductModal = ({ isOpen, onRequestClose }) => {
  const [cookies] = useCookies(['user']);
  const user = cookies.user;
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState('');
  const [productPrice, setProductPrice] = useState('');
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null)
  const [productId, setProductID] = useState('')

  //Function to add the product to the database and then add its id to the seller data 
  const handleSubmit = async() => {
    try{
      const res = await addProductAPI(productName, productPrice, selectedFile)
      setProductID(res)
      console.log(productId)
      console.log(user.username)
      await addProductId( user._id, res)
      console.log('Product added to the seller Database')
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    
    onRequestClose()
  };

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    console.log('Selected file:', file);
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onRequestClose={onRequestClose}
      contentLabel="Form Modal"
    >
      <form onSubmit={e=> e.preventDefault()}>
        <input type="text" placeholder='name of the product' value={productName} onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}/>
        <br />
        <input type="text" placeholder='price of the product' value={productPrice} onChange={(e) => setProductPrice(e.target.value)}/>
        <br />
        <input type="file" id="imageInput" name="image" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default AddProductModal
```

I want the product-id that I am getting after adding the product to add to the array in the seller database